# mySQL query to retrieve related information from 2 tables on 1 database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 tables in the same database (mySQL). I have tried to use an INNER JOIN but I have realised that the WHERE used to SELECT entries is not the same on both tables i.e.. id on properties is not the same as id on reports so I have no way of telling the query to get accurate info from the second table ( i think that's right)

anyway. below is my query. Can someone please tell me the best way to achieve the results i need to do this properly and have all of those fields populate?

cheers

```
<?php session_start();

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('DbConnector.php');

$connector = new DbConnector();

$customerid = '125';

$sql=( "SELECT DISTINCT reports.id, properties.title, reports.title, reports.date, reports.link FROM reports JOIN properties ON reports.visible = properties.customer WHERE properties.customer ='".$customerid."'" )or die( mysql_error("FAIL!!") );
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $output[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: can I know your table structure, primary key and foreign key for each table properties and reports?

Comment: Primary key for each is 'id' and the foreign key on reports that relates to properties is 'visible'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
<?php session_start();

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('DbConnector.php');

$connector = new DbConnector();

$customerid = '125';

$sql=( "SELECT DISTINCT reports.id, properties.title, reports.title, reports.date, reports.link FROM reports JOIN properties ON reports.visible = properties.visible WHERE properties.customer = '$customerid' " )or die( mysql_error("FAIL!!") );
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $output[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified more. the 'id' field on properties relates to 'visible' field on reports. I didn't build this database, I'm just trying to use what we have as best we can as they don't want to rebuild the website or database. I also should clarify that I am getting a response to the query, however, it leaves out the 'properties.title' field and I just figured I had done the Join wrong but yours is almost identical

Comment: I also saw that there was a mistake in the fact I was relating to the customer field, but this did not fix the issue anyway

Comment: could it be a problem if 2 fields are returning the same name value? i.e. "title":"value1","title":"value2"

Comment: can, you should use AS

Comment: what do you mean by AS?

Comment: sorry I'm a little bit confused at how that is going to help me with this query. Although i can definitely see how this will help me clean up the code later on

Comment: do you mean to use AS to make sure the properties.title comes back with a different name? will that fix my issue?

Comment: yes my friend. If you don't use alias, you will get interference name issue between two tables. make it unique